# how to return data from the same row after using min(date)

Tags: sql, mysql

```
select customer_id, min(order_date) as first_date, customer_pref_delivery_date
from Delivery
group by customer_id
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

Here is the input table `Delivery`:

| delivery_id | customer_id | order_date | customer_pref_delivery_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2019-08-01 | 2019-08-02 |
| 2 | 2 | 2019-08-02 | 2019-08-02 |
| 3 | 1 | 2019-08-11 | 2019-08-12 |
| 4 | 3 | 2019-08-24 | 2019-08-24 |
| 5 | 3 | 2019-08-21 | 2019-08-22 |
| 6 | 2 | 2019-08-11 | 2019-08-13 |
| 7 | 4 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 |

Here is my outcome:

| customer_id | first_date | customer_pref_delivery_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-08-01 | 2019-08-02 |
| 2 | 2019-08-02 | 2019-08-02 |
| 3 | 2019-08-21 | 2019-08-24 |
| 4 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 |

Here is exptected outcome:

| customer_id | first_date | customer_pref_delivery_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-08-01 | 2019-08-02 |
| 2 | 2019-08-02 | 2019-08-02 |
| 3 | 2019-08-21 | ***2019-08-22*** |
| 4 | 2019-08-09 | 2019-08-09 |

Why does customer 3 has customer_pref_delivery_date from a differnt row when order_date is 2019-08-24? Even tho I set it to min(order_date) and I thought SQL would return the customer_pref_delivery_date from the same row. Why is this not the case and how to fix this?

Comment: By the way, are you sure this is the query you used? That's invalid SQL syntax because you select the column `customer_pref_delivery_date` without using an aggregate function and without adding it to the `GROUP BY` clause. That's not allowed and leads to an error message, see https://dbfiddle.uk/HVouHNiv. I know there is some ugly hack in `MySQL` which allows such syntax anyway, but it is still wrong and you should disable this incorrect usage.

Comment: @JonasMetzler, yeah MySQL allows it that prob why my results are not right.

Comment: @JonasMetzler, I just added an expected table.

Comment: @JonasMetzler, I wanted to select the customer_pref_delivery_date that's at the same row with min(first_date). MIN(customer_pref_delivery_date) does the job on the example table, but it might not be the case for a larger table.

Comment: @JonasMetzler meaning that I want to find all the data rows with min(order_date) group by customer_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you want to select the column `customer_pref_delivery_date`, but didn't add it to the `GROUP BY` clause or put it in an aggregate function.

That's generally **invalid** SQL syntax. So it's sheer "luck" the query is executed at all and doesn't produce an error message.

One option to get your desired result is to use a `CTE` that fetches the `MIN(order_date)` for each customer_id and then use an outer query to add the other columns:

```
WITH minData AS
  (SELECT customer_id, MIN(order_date) AS order_date
   FROM Delivery
   GROUP BY customer_id)
SELECT
  customer_id, 
  order_date AS first_date, 
  customer_pref_delivery_date 
FROM Delivery
WHERE
  (customer_id, order_date) IN 
    (SELECT customer_id, order_date FROM minData)
ORDER BY customer_id;
```

The `IN` clause (you could also use `INNER JOIN` instead) makes sure to get the relevant rows only.

Here a [sample fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oa-39Cuh) based on your data.

**To prevent such issues in future**: As mentioned above, you should pay attention to use a valid syntax when using `GROUP BY`. Those columns you want to select must either be added to the `GROUP BY` clause or used within an aggregate function like `MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG` etc.

Otherwise, when not following these rules, incorrect results will be the best case you will encounter. Mostly, you will get such an error message:

> Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Delivery.customer_pref_delivery_date' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Unfortunately, `MySQL` has some ugly hack which allows to use incorrect syntax. If you observe this is the case, I highly recommend to disable it. Thus, you will avoid exactly such issues as explained in your question.

Following command should stop this mode and enable the "standard" mode:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

Doing so, you won't wonder about unexpected results, but will be informed about an issue with your `GROUP BY` syntax, so it's much easier to fix the problem.